# What does this symbol mean in Mercurial?

Tags: mercurial

[image]

I've majorly refactored my project. I've added some new classes, but I've also RightClick > Deleted classes from within Visual Studio Solution Explorer.

What does the ! symbol mean?

All of the items marked with ! were things I've deleted in VS2010. Will this delete them from the repository as well?

Comment: You have a question about `hg status`? See `hg help status` for the solution. Let me know if the help is not clear enough so that I can improve it.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Those files are "missing."  You haven't explicitly removed those files from the repository, and yet mercurial can't find them.

If you commit with `hg commit --addremove` then mercurial will remove all of the missing files from the repository.  In this case, I think this is what you want to do - you've purposely deleted these files, and you don't want them to appear in future versions of your code.  You'll still be able to go to an earlier version and call those files back if you want to.

Comment: Groovy! Thank you for clearing that up. So I would go **hg commit -m "tqerqwer" --addremove**?

Comment: Yep! Stack overflow is making me write more than "Yep!" so I'll reaffirm: "Exactly!"  There's a great tutorial at hginit.com

Comment: `hg addr -n` is useful if you want to do a dry-run to see what files will be added or removed.

Comment: You can also do `hg addremove -s 80` before committing and mercurial will automatically detect renames/copies for files which are still 80% similar. That way you can follow history across renames and mercurial will know what to do when merging with branches without the rename.

Comment: Also `hg amend --addremove` if you already committed and realized this afterwards

Answer (score 3):

As @Riley [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5159284/what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-mercurial/5159372#5159372), it means they're missing.  An alternative method of removing them from the repository is to use `hg remove --after <filename>`.  The comments in the [hgbook](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/mercurial-in-daily-use.html) point out the you can issue the command without specifying the filename, and it will remove all of the missing files, too, but it does complain for every file that isn't missing.

Comment: Yeah, and this is safer.  You shouldn't get in the habit of just tacking --addremove on the end of every commit.